# Passing std::ranges::views as parameters in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have a method that prints a list of integers (my actual method is a bit more complicated but it is also read-only):

```
void printElements(const std::vector<int> &integersList)
{
    std::for_each(integersList.begin(), integersList.end(), [](const auto& e){
        std::cout << e << "\n";
    });
}
```

Now suppose I have the following vector:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

Then I want to print even numbers only. To do this, I thought of employing the new `std::ranges` feature in C++20. I know that you can do this as follows:

```
auto evenList = vec | std::views::filter([](auto i){ return i % 2 == 0; });
```

Now I would like to call `printElements(evenList)`, however this obviously won't compile. What would be the solution to this? Also can I write a single function that will both print a `std::vector` *and* an object of the same type as my `evenList`? Or do I need to write two separate functions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make `printElements` take any object by making it a function template. This will instantiate it for `views` as well as `vector`s.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

void printElements(std::ranges::input_range auto&& range) {
    std::ranges::for_each(range, [](const auto& e) { std::cout << e << '\n'; });
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3r7ss7qd1)

or:

```cpp
// ...
#include <iterator>

void printElements(std::ranges::input_range auto&& range) {
    using T = std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(range)>;
    std::ranges::copy(range, std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W8dY63eq1)